# Facebook, Twitter, and Google +1 buttons using only HTML (No Javascript)

Tags: html, facebook, url, twitter, google-plus-one

I would like to know if there is a method to create "share" buttons for Facebook, Twitter and Google +1 using only HTML, without any Javascript having to be inserted into the code at any point.

For example, you can use the methods described below to create these buttons dynamically; however they all end up loading Javascript dynamically and creating their own code behind the scenes:

- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/
- http://twitter.com/about/resources/buttons
- http://www.google.com/webmasters/+1/button/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The following links will register the appropriate Likes, Tweets and +1s:

- http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://example.com
- http://twitter.com/share?url=http://example.com&text=Description
- https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/confirm?hl=en&url=http://example.com

These links will work for Wordpress:

*Facebook*

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php if(is_home()){echo home_url();}else{the_permalink();} ?>" target="_blank" title="Share this page on Facebook">Like</a>
```

*Twitter*

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/share?url=<?php if(is_home()){echo home_url();}else{the_permalink();} ?>&text=<?php the_title(); ?>" target="_blank" title="Tweet this page on Twitter">Tweet</a>
```

*Google +1*

```
<a href="https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/confirm?hl=en&url=<?php if(is_home()){echo home_url();}else{the_permalink();} ?>" target="_blank" title="Plus one this page on Google">+1</a>
```

Comment: Does the Facebook url take any more params? Or is it just `u`?

Comment: @henrywright It seems Facebook now prefers a different syntax; the URL in the answer strill works, but here is more information on how to do this using the share dialog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog#redirect Regarding options for the legacy URL, see this post: http://ar.zu.my/how-to-really-customize-the-deprecated-facebook-sharer-dot-php/

Answer (score 6):

google plus not working in the above example.

I used this for google plus.

```
<div id="custom-google-button">
  <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?&hl=en&url=YOUR_URL_to_share" target="_blank">google+</a>
</div>
```

In Wordpress :

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?hl=en&url=<?php if(is_home()){echo home_url();}else{the_permalink();} ?>" target="_blank" title="Plus one this page on Google">google+</a>
```

Linkedin :

```
<div id="custom-linkedin-button">
  <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=YOUR_URL_to_share" target="_blank">Linkedin</a>
</div>
```

In Wordpress :

```
<a href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=<?php if(is_home()){echo home_url();}else{the_permalink();} ?>" target="_blank">Linkedin</a>
```

Sources :

- https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/share/
- https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/share-linkedin

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty useful article that provides the answer you are looking for without using any PHP - http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AddSocialSharingLinksToYourBlogWithoutWidgetJavaScript.aspx

**TWITTER**

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=YOURURLHERE&text=YOURPOSTTITLEHERE&via=YOURTWITTERNAMEHERE">Twitter</a>
```

**FACEBOOK**

```
<a href="https://facebook.com/sharer.php?u=YOURURLHERE">Facebook</a>
```

**GOOGLE+**

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=YOURURLHERE">Google+</a>
```