# How to implement a social button based on its URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

It seems that social buttons (Facebook,Google,Twitter) usually are put in an iframe. It seems I can isolate the social button by following the iframe source URL, for example a tweet button:

[Follow this URL to see the tweet button](http://platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.1407888064.html#_=1408270009347&count=none&id=twitter-widget-0&lang=en&original_referer=http%3A%2F%2Ffiddle.jshell.net%2F_display%2F&size=m&text=-%20jsFiddle%20demo&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nu.nl)

My question is: How do I put this button on my page? The reason I want it out of the Iframe is because I would like to click on it programmatically eg Jquery/javascript.

Comment: I suggest you to read API of those services

Comment: I was hoping for a universal method to the problem without taking a course at Facebook, and then at Twitter, and then ...

Comment: Universal method is to read their API and follow it

Comment: Just want to share this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988815/facebook-twitter-and-google-1-buttons-using-only-html-no-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible by design, and besides that against the TOS of these services. You cannot post on an arbitrary user's facebook or twitter without their approval.

Comment: Great answer over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988815/facebook-twitter-and-google-1-buttons-using-only-html-no-javascript